# How to access windows files in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, media

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on LEGACY and Windows 8.1 on UEFI . I have my media ( movie songs and video songs) in "MY MUSIC" and "MY VIDEOS" folders in windows.

I am able to access different hard drives except C drive ( windows ). Now can someone please tell me how to access those "my music" and "my videos" folders in UBUNTU? because i cant find them in ubuntu.

Output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0   260M  0 part 
├─sda2    8:2    0   1.5G  0 part 
├─sda3    8:3    0   260M  0 part 
├─sda4    8:4    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda5    8:5    0 245.7G  0 part 
├─sda6    8:6    0   350M  0 part 
├─sda7    8:7    0  97.7G  0 part 
├─sda8    8:8    0  72.3G  0 part 
├─sda9    8:9    0  25.4G  0 part /
├─sda10   8:10   0  22.3G  0 part 
├─sda11   8:11   0     2M  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda12   8:12   0     1M  0 part 
sr0      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: post the output of `lsblk` command in your question.

Comment: Here is the lsblk output. http://paste.ubuntu.com/7289388/

Comment: do you know on which partition, your stuff's are located?

Comment: sda 5. because usually my music folder is on c drive, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the below commands on terminal to mount your 240 GB `/dev/sda5` partition.

```
sudo mkdir /media/windows
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /media/windows
```

Now your `/dev/sda5` partition will be mounted inside `/media/windows` folder.You can browse for the files inside `/media/windows` through nautilus.

Comment: i get this.
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Comment: yes, follow this simple step.shutdown and reboot into windows.Restart your windows os (**not shutdown**).On the grub select Ubuntu.Now you can be able to access that windows partition in Ubuntu.

Comment: but i dont have a menu for selecting. I get ubuntu when i select LEGACY, i get Windows when i select UEFI, in the BIOS. i cant get both of them at a time.

Comment: Ok change to UEFI in bios and boot to windows.Make a restart, it boots again to windows.Witout opening any of your partitions, shutdown your pc.Change to legacy in bios and boot Ubuntu.There you go.

Comment: still Same error msg.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Thanks, but i already have disabled the fast startup earlier. Will the read only thing work? if so, please tell me the command for mouting it read only.

Comment: try all the answers, given in that question.

Comment: Your command worked with a little modification of read only. Thankyou very much.

Comment: Do i have to unmount it before shutting down in ubuntu?

Comment: yep, How did you get that work?

Comment: read-only? you mean this `sudo chmod 777 /media/windows`

Comment: sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda5 /media/windows

Comment: where did you get this ^^ ?

Comment: In the Link you provided me.