# Cross-OS filesystem Windows/Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, filesystem

If I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10, can I browse my files that are in Windows while I'm in the Ubuntu partition?

Comment: Yes, you can. But you will need to shut down Windows properly to be able to amend them.

Comment: I am 100% sure. Everyone does it.

Comment: But you need to shut down Windows properly.

Comment: Otherwise you will have only read-only access to the Windows files.

Comment: @Pilot6 Won't he have to mount it as mentioned [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/451139/602680)?

Comment: @OwenHines no, shouldn't have to. If Windows has Fast Boot enabled, is hibernated or does the thing where it doesn't cooperate anyway, then `ntfsfix` needs to be used.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Ah, ok. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: I do not like ntfsfix. It is better o shut down Windows or mount as read-only.